# K8S how to get an overview of warnings

Tags: kubernetes

I have a k3s cluster set up in my home lab. I find that i Iversen a lot of warnings that i mainly get by using an app called kubenav
[image: kubenav warnings]

I am aware that I can describe a pod using `kubectl describe pod podname`

Is there a better command to see all warnings in all namespaces?

Comment: if you use the lens, you can see the events(all type of events contains warning) in one tab.

Comment: is "the lens" a kubectl command?

Comment: I think @dolpin referees to https://k8slens.dev/desktop.html. I use their tool for all out edge environments because it gives great insight with minimum effort.